# Is there any way to use methods from interface and class specified when creating object from interface referance?

Tags: java

We got this scenario:

```
public class Shape{
    private String type;
   
}

public interface ShapeI{
    String calculateField();
}

public class Circle extends Shape implements ShapeI{

    private double radius;  
  
    @Override
    public String calculateField() {
        return "PiRadisSQ";
    }

    public void circleMethod() {
        System.out.println("circleMethod");
    }   
}

public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShapeI circle = new Circle();
        circle.calculateField(); // can use it
        circle.circleMethod(); // can't use it
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use Cicrcle class method `circleMethod()` when creating object with interface referance? I cant figure out how to create such a hierarchy.

Comment: You can't do this, and you shouldn't be allowed to do this.

Comment: This doesn't look the right way to do this. Allowing this essentially makes you able to call circleMethod() on ShapeI. Someday, you might as well have another shape, say a Square. Initialising ShapeI circle = new Square() would then be legal but circle.cirecleMethod() would be 100% against the laws.
Thus, this is not allowed and should never be.

Answer (score 0):

circleMethod() is logically spécifique to Circles and does not apply to all Shapes. The interface methods must be implemented by all Classes which implement it.
The interface can therefore include methods which are applicable to all Shapes,area, perimeter etc, but will be implemented in different ways according to the shape in question.